# Qual a diferença de concordância verbal e nominal?

Tags: concordância-verbal, concordância-nominal

Qual a diferença de concordância verbal e nominal? Pode haver concordância verbal e nominal na mesma frase?

Comment: Could you mayeb add examples for "concordância verbal e nominal"?

Comment: @Earthliŋ por que escreveu em inglês? Então, eu estou postando perguntas desta maneira por este motivo: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/60/8 No entanto formulei uma resposta para não voltar a ter problema, porém se tiver uma resposta melhor que a acabei de adicionar não existe em responder. A minha intenção é gerar participação dos demais membros os privilegiando com perguntas que agreguem informação para o site e eles ganham pontos e se sentem estimulados a participar. Compreende?

Comment: Escrevi em inglês porque não falo português muito bem, mas vindo suas outras questões sei que você entende inglês bem. Eu não entendo muito bem a sua motivação para adicionar este tipo de questão, mas tudo bem. Com relação à questão mesma, nesta forma acho que é imprecisa ("unclear what you're asking") e muito geral (talvez "too broad"?) e por isso perguntei se poderia ser mas claro. Mas como já postou uma reposta, não sei o que posso fazer para melhorar a questão. Posso aplicar downvote ou vote de fechar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concordância verbal

É a correta flexão do verbo, em número e pessoa, com relação ao sujeito da oração. Concordância, ato ou efeito de harmonizar flexões de palavras em uma frase, neste contexto pode ser entendido como "se refere de forma correta".

Exemplos:

- **João** *faz* o dever de casa.
- **Os alunos** *fazem* o dever de casa.

### Concordância nominal

A concordância nominal se baseia na relação entre um substantivo (ou pronome, ou numeral substantivo) e as palavras que a ele se ligam para caracterizá-lo (artigos, adjetivos,  pronomes adjetivos, numerais adjetivos e particípios). Basicamente, ocupa-se  da relação entre nomes.

> Lembre-se: normalmente, o substantivo funciona como núcleo de um termo da oração, e o adjetivo, como adjunto adnominal.

Por Exemplo:

O substantivo permanece no singular e coloca-se o artigo antes do último adjetivo:

- Admiro a **cultura** espanhola e *a* portuguesa.

O substantivo vai para o plural e omite-se o artigo antes do adjetivo:

- Admiro as **culturas** espanhola e portuguesa.

Fontes:

- http://www.soportugues.com.br/secoes/sint/sint59.php
- [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordância_verbal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concord%C3%A2ncia_verbal)
- [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concordância_nominal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concord%C3%A2ncia_nominal)