# Regra do plural em frase: "encontrar" ou "encontrarem", "utiliza" ou "utilizam"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, número-gramatical

No português brasileiro, qual das duas frases abaixo utiliza a forma correta das palavras "utilizar" e "encontrar"? Gostaria de uma explicação detalhada sobre o porquê da resposta.

"97% das pessoas do Rio de Janeiro **utilizam** a internet para **encontrarem** produtos e serviços"

ou

"97% das pessoas do Rio de Janeiro **utiliza** a internet para **encontrar** produtos e serviços"

Comment: Que interessante, em Português europeu eu utilizaria uma *terceira* opção: "97% das pessoas do Rio de Janeiro **utilizam** a internet para **encontrar** produtos e serviços".

Comment: @ANeves Em português brasileiro também se usaria "encontrar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Apesar da discordância entre os gramáticos, ambas construções estão corretas.

#### Explicação

Na concordância verbal, o verbo deve — em regra — concordar com o sujeito da oração.

> O *poeta* **é** fingidor
>   Fingidor **é** o *poeta*
>   Os *poetas* **são** fingidores

Observe que o verbo *é* (ser) concorda em número com o substantivo *poeta*.

Quando o sujeito possui porcentagem, há uma discordância entre os gramáticos.

Para *Fernando Pestana*, o verbo pode concordar com o numerador, no caso de fração; com o valor inteiro, no caso de percentagem; ou com seu especificador. Portanto, para Pestana, as orações a seguir estão corretas:

> 97% das **pessoas** do Rio de Janeiro **utilizam** a internet para **encontrar** produtos e serviços.

> **1%** das pessoas do Rio de Janeiro **utiliza** a internet para **encontrar** produtos e serviços.

> 1% das **pessoas** do Rio de Janeiro **utilizam** a internet para **encontrar** produtos e serviços.

Ainda de acordo com Pestana, “se o numeral vier precedido de determinante, o verbo concordará apenas com o numeral”:

> **Os** 30% da população não **sabem** o que é viver mal.

O gramático *Evanildo Bechara*, no entanto, afirma que “nas linguagens modernas em que entram expressões numéricas de porcentagem, a tendência é fazer concordar o verbo com o termo preposicionado que especifica a referência numérica”. Para ele, as orações seguir estão corretas:

> 97% das **pessoas** do Rio de Janeiro **utilizam** a internet para **encontrar** produtos e serviços.

> 1% das **pessoas** do Rio de Janeiro **utilizam** a internet para **encontrar** produtos e serviços.

<sup>**Para saber mais sobre concordância verbal:**

[O que é “Concordância Verbal”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/315/2759)

[Qual a diferença de concordância verbal e nominal?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/517/2759)

[“[…] você ou Fulano já pensou/pensaram sobre […]” - concordância verbal](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/voc%c3%aa-ou-fulano-j%c3%a1-pensou-pensaram-sobre-concord%c3%a2ncia-verbal)

[“noventa por cento é… ou noventa por cento são…?”](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3428/2759)

[Havia ou haviam?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1791/havia-ou-haviam)</sup>

<sup>[**Fonte e Referências bibliográficas**](https://github.com/valdeir2000/pt-br/blob/master/answers/6333.md)</sup>